# installing windows service twice using InstallUtil.exe creating issues with state managment

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have created on Windows Service in C#. I am also maintaining a state to restore some parameter while un-installing it. I Have written a code like below

```
    protected override void OnAfterInstall(IDictionary savedState)
    {   
            SaveInitState(savedState);
            base.OnBeforeInstall(savedState);

    }
    protected override void OnAfterUninstall(IDictionary savedState)
    {       
            RestoreState(savedState);
            base.OnAfterUninstall(savedState);
    }
```

My Code works perfectly fine when i install the service and then unintall it using InstallUtil.exe. i.e. state is restored correctly

But i am getting problem with following scenario.
If I first install the service and then suppose try to install it again, it gives me error "Service Already exits" which is correct. But when i uninstall it after previous step, service is uninstalling correctly but my state is not restored in this case.

My guess is my overridden function  ***OnAfterUninstall*** function is not calling in above scenario. I also verified this using event log in this function.

Comment: And what about Rollback? Are you calling SaveInitState state OnAfterRollbackRollback too? Or maybe delete the saved state (or restore the previous one) if the rollback was performed?

Comment: At a guess, the failed second install is calling OnAfterInstall which is overwriting the previously saved state.  You might need to check whether there is already a saved state before overwriting it.

Comment: OnAfterInstall is not calling in second install. i verified it using logs.